# Difference Between Variable and Identifier

Tags: java

I am new to programming and learning Java these Days. I have read that Identifiers are "names given to variables and many other things in java like classes etc". But I confused that if identifier is a name given to variable so how variable will have its own personality.
For example, I have a Book in real world, which can be variable in programming and its name is Book so Book will be both Variable and Identifier. How are these two things distinguish and different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every variable has a name, which is an identifier. Likewise every class has a name, which is also an identifier - as is a method name, and a package name. There are restrictions on what an identifier can look like - for example, it can't start with a number, or include whitespace.

So for example, in this program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

the identifiers used are:

- `Test`
- `main`
- `args`
- `x`
- `System`
- `out`
- `println`

However, only `args` and `x` are variables declared within the code you've given. `out` is also a variable, but it's declared in the `System` type.

The same identifier can refer to different things in different contexts, even within the same program. For example:

```
public void method1() {
    String x = "";
    System.out.println(x);
}

public void method1() {
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Here the identifier `x` is used in both methods - but each time it only refers to the variable declared within the method.

An identifier is just part of how you represent your program as text, whereas a variable is part of your *logical* program.

It's not entirely clear to me where your confusion stems from in the first place, but hopefully this can help you a little... you can *probably* just ignore the term identifier entirely for the most part. Just know that variables (and other things) have names.

Comment: It means that Identifier does not reserves memory or piece of memory but variable allocates piece of memory.

Comment: @SyedShaharyaarHussain: Well, I wouldn't express it that way, because they're really *very* different concepts. Variables are how you store information - identifiers are just ways of identifying "things" (variables, methods, types, packages etc). Each variable has a name, which must be an identifier. It also has a storage location.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood these two terms.

Answer (score 9):

An identifier is the name of a variable, class, function etc. You distinguish it just same way as you do your name from yourself.

So if the memory holds a value at a certain memory address, instead of you having to go fetch that value from the specific address, you just refer to the identifier.

Just like saying "I'm looking for Syed" instead of having to say "Give me the person at these specific coordinates in space"

Comment: Well, identifiers are used for various things - not just variables.

Answer (score 0):

An **identifier** is a token that follows the rules of token and also can be used to identify something. an identifier can also be used for the name of:
**Variables/Literals/Keywords/Class/Method**.............. and etc.
A **variable** is an identifier which is used to contain some value. The value contained by a variable can be changed (varied) any time during execution of program.